# Where's the best place to report bugs regarding the Azure Portal website?

Tags: azure

Does anyone know what the appropriate channel to report bugs (such as broken links) regarding the Azure Portal? I found there is an [Azure feedback website](http://feedback.windowsazure.com) but it seems to be more for feature requests and ideas rather than defects.

Comment: File a support ticket if you have a support plan.

Comment: I ended up letting support know about the issue since I do have a support plan.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Feedback for Azure **Portal**: [aka.ms/azureportalfeedback](http://aka.ms/azureportalfeedback)

Azure Portal Twitter: [@AzurePortal](https://twitter.com/azureportal)

You can also report bugs using feedback button (smile) in the nav bar (top right):

[image: Azure Portal Feedback]

Comment: It seems like this is the more current answer and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure the feedback button is still valid. I don't see any indication that you are filing a bug or that you'll be able to follow up with them.

Comment: @DanFriedman: at the bottom there is checkbox "Microsoft can email you about your feedback" - make sure you check it if you want a follow up

Comment: This is not an answer either.  Some of us have Twitter (and many other sites) blocked by our companies.  The other is a suggestion site.

Answer (score 11):

You can always send a quick tweet:

**https://twitter.com/Azure**

or post on Azure MSDN Forum:

**https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/forums/**

Comment: Windows azure twitter handle is not valid

Comment: The other link is useless as well.

Comment: Agree with the comments on this 'answer'. Both links are useless.
MS shutdown public bug reporting a few years back. The only way to submit a bug report is through a support ticket. It's one of the reasons there's so many bugs!